# Relationship between TypeRep and "Type" GADT

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

In [Scrap your boilerplate reloaded](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.100.6601), the authors describe a new presentation of [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=7D102D3B946AD3B5E0041F2863132665?doi=10.1.1.1.3176), which is supposed to be equivalent to the original.

However, one difference is that they assume a finite, closed set of "base" types, encoded with a GADT

```
data Type :: * -> * where
  Int :: Type Int
  List :: Type a -> Type [a]
  ...
```

In the original SYB, type-safe cast is used, implemented using the `Typeable` class.

My questions are:

- What is the relationship between these two approaches?
- Why was the GADT representation chosen for the "SYB Reloaded" presentation?

Comment: That sounds like a similar approach taken [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-27764-4_4?LI=true#page-1) with the universal `Univ` type, but I've only skimmed that paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I am one of the authors of the "SYB Reloaded" paper.]

**TL;DR** We really just used it because it seemed more beautiful to us. The class-based `Typeable` approach is more practical. The `Spine` view can be combined with the `Typeable` class and does not depend on the `Type` GADT.

The paper states this in its conclusions:

> Our implementation handles the two central ingredients of generic programming differently from the original SYB paper: we use overloaded functions with
>   explicit type arguments instead of overloaded functions based on a type-safe
>   cast [1](http://www.andres-loeh.de/OpenDatatypes.html) or a class-based extensible scheme [20]; and we use the explicit spine
>   view rather than a combinator-based approach. Both changes are independent
>   of each other, and have been made with clarity in mind: we think that the structure of the SYB approach is more visible in our setting, and that the relations
>   to PolyP and Generic Haskell become clearer. We have revealed that while the
>   spine view is limited in the class of generic functions that can be written, it is
>   applicable to a very large class of data types, including GADTs.
>
> Our approach cannot be used easily as a library, because the encoding of
>   overloaded functions using explicit type arguments requires the extensibility of
>   the Type data type and of functions such as toSpine. One can, however, incorporate Spine into the SYB library while still using the techniques of the SYB
>   papers to encode overloaded functions.

So, the choice of using a GADT for type representation is one we made mainly for clarity. As Don states in his answer, there are some obvious advantages in this representation, namely that it maintains static information about what type a type representation is for, and that it allows us to implement cast without any further magic, and in particular without the use of `unsafeCoerce`. Type-indexed functions can also be implemented directly by using pattern matching on the type, and without falling back to various combinators such as `mkQ` or `extQ`.

Fact is that I (and I think the co-authors) simply were not very fond of the `Typeable` class. (In fact, I'm still not, although it is finally becoming a bit more disciplined now in that GHC adds auto-deriving for `Typeable`, makes it kind-polymorphic, and will ultimately remove the possibility to define your own instances.) In addition, `Typeable` wasn't quite as established and widely known as it is perhaps now, so it seemed appealing to "explain" it by using the GADT encoding. And furthermore, this was the time when we were also thinking about adding [open datatypes](http://www.andres-loeh.de/OpenDatatypes.html) to Haskell, thereby alleviating the restriction that the GADT is closed.

So, to summarize: If you actually need dynamic type information only for a closed universe, I'd always go for the GADT, because you can use pattern matching to define type-indexed functions, and you do not have to rely on `unsafeCoerce` nor advanced compiler magic. If the universe is open, however, which is quite common, certainly for the generic programming setting, then the GADT approach might be instructive, but isn't practical, and using `Typeable` is the way to go.

However, as we also state in the conclusions of the paper, the choice of `Type` over `Typeable` isn't a prerequisite for the other choice we're making, namely to use the `Spine` view, which I think is more important and really the core of the paper.

The paper itself shows (in Section 8) a variation inspired by the ["Scrap your Boilerplate with Class"](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/syb3/) paper, which uses a `Spine` view with a class constraint instead. But we can also do a more direct development, which I show in the following. For this, we'll use `Typeable` from `Data.Typeable`, but define our own `Data` class which, for simplicity, just contains the `toSpine` method:

```
class Typeable a => Data a where
  toSpine :: a -> Spine a
```

The `Spine` datatype now uses the `Data` constraint:

```
data Spine :: * -> * where
  Constr  :: a -> Spine a
  (:<>:)  :: (Data a) => Spine (a -> b) -> a -> Spine b
```

The function `fromSpine` is as trivial as with the other representation:

```
fromSpine :: Spine a -> a
fromSpine (Constr x) = x
fromSpine (c :<>: x) = fromSpine c x
```

Instances for `Data` are trivial for flat types such as `Int`:

```
instance Data Int where
  toSpine = Constr
```

And they're still entirely straightforward for structured types such as binary trees:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

instance Data a => Data (Tree a) where
  toSpine Empty        = Constr Empty
  toSpine (Node l x r) = Constr Node :<>: l :<>: x :<>: r
```

The paper then goes on and defines various generic functions, such as `mapQ`. These definitions hardly change. We only get class constraints for `Data a =>` where the paper has function arguments of `Type a ->`:

```
mapQ :: Query r -> Query [r]
mapQ q = mapQ' q . toSpine

mapQ' :: Query r -> (forall a. Spine a -> [r])
mapQ' q (Constr c) = []
mapQ' q (f :<>: x) = mapQ' q f ++ [q x]
```

Higher-level functions such as `everything` also just lose their explicit type arguments (and then actually look exactly the same as in original SYB):

```
everything :: (r -> r -> r) -> Query r -> Query r
everything op q x = foldl op (q x) (mapQ (everything op q) x)
```

As I said above, if we now want to define a generic sum function summing up all `Int` occurrences, we cannot pattern match anymore, but have to fall back to `mkQ`, but `mkQ` is defined purely in terms of `Typeable` and completely independent of `Spine`:

```
mkQ :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => r -> (b -> r) -> a -> r
(r `mkQ` br) a = maybe r br (cast a)
```

And then (again exactly as in original SYB):

```
sum :: Query Int
sum = everything (+) sumQ

sumQ :: Query Int
sumQ = mkQ 0 id
```

For some of the stuff later in the paper (e.g., adding constructor information), a bit more work is needed, but it can all be done. So using `Spine` really does not depend on using `Type` at all.

Answer (score 5):

Well, obviously the `Typeable` use is open -- new variants can be added after the fact, and without modifying the original definitions.

The important change though is that in that `TypeRep` is untyped. That is, there is no connection between the runtime type , `TypeRep`, and the static type it encodes. With the GADT approach we can encode the mapping between a type `a` and its `Type`, given by the GADT `Type a`.

We thus bake in evidence for the type rep being statically linked to its origin type, and can write statically typed dynamic application (for example) using `Type a` as evidence that we have a runtime `a`.

In the older TypeRep case, we have no such evidence and it comes down to runtime string equality, and a coerce and hope for the best through `fromDynamic`.

Compare the signatures:

```
toDyn :: Typeable a => a -> TypeRep -> Dynamic
```

versus GADT style:

```
toDyn :: Type a => a -> Type a -> Dynamic
```

I can't fake my type evidence, and I can use that later when reconstructing things, to e.g. lookup the type class instances for `a` when all I have is a `Type a`.

Comment: I don't agree. In the GADT case, the type is later erased by existential quantification (see the definition of `Spine`). Thus, in both cases you recover the type at run time — using the GADT tag in one case, and `TypeRep` in the other.

Comment: Actually, the signatures are `toDyn :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic` vs. `toDyn :: Type a -> a -> Dynamic`. It is true that the `Typeable` class is internally implemented using an untyped `TypeRep`, but only few functions work with `TypeRep` directly. Yes, you can fake `Typeable` instances until defining your own `Typeable` instances becomes disallowed.